# Intl.DateTimeFormat.format() fails in Edge browser?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

This maybe a long shot but has anyone else seen Edge throw a generic error when just running `new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format()` from the console in the latest version of Edge(41.16299.248.0) on Windows 10? So far I've only been able to reproduce on one specific user's machine.
It just gives a `SCRIPT65535` error.

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you got any update on this? Or possible workarounds? Got same issue on multiple user machines, all upgraded from win7 to win10, same build, and yet 1/3 of them fail. Reinstalling EDGE Package, trying different user profiles, or trying to fix EDGE in SysApps didn't help.

Comment: @CrudaLilium I added an answer with what I ended up figuring out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I eventually found the cause and came up with a workaround.
A user on the windows forum posted this related issue and discovered the root cause in a windows system dll that edge uses for formatting dates: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/dce1f04c-8c06-4398-93a5-127393a428dd/uwpccalendarchangetimezone-throws-eunexpected?forum=wpdevelop

Essentially it's caused by registry value that should have been removed during a windows update but on some systems it's still present so the function throws. To verify it's the same cause I deleted this registry value on the effected system (it's an obsolete time zone) and it fixed the issue:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Armenian Standard Time
```

Obviously I didn't want to force my users to update their registries so when my app starts up I polyfill that portion of the `Intl` api if it's broken in that browser:

```js
// Only polyfill DateTimeFormat if the call fails
try {
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format();
} catch (error) {
  Object.defineProperty(Intl, 'DateTimeFormat', {
    value: DateTimeFormatPolyfill,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, told the same to the client and the issue was the same and got fixed. We will also make polyfill once we can.